# Spring Multi Module Project

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot, dependency-management

I have to create a Spring Boot project that will have a web interactive part and a batch part a,d both with the same DB (so they share the DAOs and Services), I wonder how to do it and I guess that the best approach is to create a Multi Module Project

something like this

```
<modules>
   <module>core</module>
   <module>batchApplication</module>
   <module>userApplication</module>
</modules>
```

But, do I have to create more than 1 pom and project ??? or I can do it in the same pom ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a parent pom which has the spring-boot as a parent, then a directory and with pom for each child project.  Your parent pom will be like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.barclaycard</groupId>
    <artifactId>bc-alu</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>Barclaycard Address LookUp</name>

    <modules>
        <module>bc-alu-ref</module>
        <module>bc-alu-web</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

See here for mutil module project https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html